# How to make start menu for Javascript game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok this will be long please bear with me (Im new to Javascript programming btw)

So our task in school is to get an open source game and modify it

The one I found is good it's a tank shooter, however the thing is the game instantly start upon opening the index.html I wanted to add start menu/button and have option for 2,3,or 4 players

Here is the code in index.html, I'll put my observations next to it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Neon Tankz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.play.js"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/array-extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/vector-extensions.js"></script>

    <script src="Entities/sprite-entity.js"></script>

    <script src="Entities/Map/tile.js"></script>
    <script src="Entities/Map/grid.js"></script>
    <script src="Entities/Map/game-map.js"></script>

    <script src="Entities/Scoreboard/score.js"></script>
    <script src="Entities/Scoreboard/scoreboard.js"></script>

    <script src="Entities/bullet.js"></script>
    <script src="Entities/cannon.js"></script>
    <script src="Entities/player.js"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black;display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div>

        <input type="button" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" onclick="location.reload(true);"
            value="Reload">
        <button onclick="stopMusic()"> Staph Moosic</button>
        <button id="mylink" onclick="myclick()">
            Load
        </button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You might be confused about the `load`, `reload` and `Staph Moosic`

- Load = is a testing button for start or loading game,
- Reload = reloads the game, or refresh the browser,
- Staph Moosic = stops the music (I added a music in main.js)

Here are the observations I noticed and what I did:
main.js has `preload()` and `load()` function and it is the file where I can modify no. of players, removing it will leave the index blank

So I assumed that with bunch of loaded scripts, main.js is needed to run?
So I tried to make another copy of main.js (main2.js) but this file is modified to only two players
and changed the previous to

```
<script src= "main2.js">
```

and it works, the game started with two players only.

At this point, I don't know what solution I can do apart from creating multiple copies of index.html (rename each of them) and each has different main.js depending on how many players 
and have index.html to just an html that links to those multiple htmls

I know it's kind of weird solution are there other solutions?

EDIT 
This is the code in main.js

```
/*Im trying to add more maps value1 and value2 are for the maps,
Currently there are two maps (map1.txt and map2.txt)
It doesn't do anything much, don't mind this lool
*/

var value1 = "1";
var value2 = "2";

//This is for the background music
var myMusic;
//This code is to make the myMusic loop
myMusic = new Audio("Images/bgMusic.wav");
myMusic.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
//This code is to play music
myMusic.play();


function start() {
    decision = true;
}
const config = {

    screen: {
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,

    },
    players: [],

    groups: {},
    bullets: {
        deathTimer: 4000
    },
    mapTile: {
        dimension: 20
        //this changes the size of the map previously 22
    }
};


function preload() {


    loadStrings("Entities/Map/map" + value2 + ".txt", mapText => config.map = new GameMap(mapText));

    for (const group of ["players", "bullets", "tiles"]) {
        config.groups[group] = new Group();
    }

    function load() {

        function removePlayer() {
            config.players.remove(this);

            if (config.players.length === 1) {
                let resetBoard = false;

                for (const score in config.scoreboard.scores) {
                    if (config.scoreboard.scores[score].value > 8) {
                        config.scoreboard.reset();
                        resetBoard = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!resetBoard) {
                    config.scoreboard.scores[config.players[0].name].increment();


                }
                //in my observation, the player score which is below will only increment if that player stays
                //removing this, will not change the score no matter who survives

                for (const player of config.players) {
                    player.destroy();

                }

                config.players.length = 0; //idk what this do but setting it to other value makes the screen hang after one wins
                load();
            }
        }
         //the no. of players can be determined
         //When you remove this config.players.push...
         //A player will be removed with no errors
        config.players.push(new Player("Player1", "Happy", {
            forward: 87, // W
            backward: 83, // S
            rotateLeft: 65, // A
            rotateRight: 68, // D
            shoot: 81 // Q      this is the fire button for the player 1
        }, removePlayer));

        config.players.push(new Player("Player2", "Neutral", {
            forward: 73, // I
            backward: 75, // K
            rotateLeft: 74, // J
            rotateRight: 76, // L
            shoot: 85 // U      // this is the fire button for the player 2
        }, removePlayer));

        config.players.push(new Player("Player3", "Smiley", {
            forward: 38, // Up arrow
            backward: 40, // Down arrow
            rotateLeft: 37, // Left arrow
            rotateRight: 39, // Right arrow
            shoot: 191 // Forward slash ('/')   this is the fire button for the player 3
        }, removePlayer));

        config.players.push(new Player("Player4", "Neo", {
            //the name "smiley" refers to the image that is provided
            forward: 84, // T
            backward: 71, // G
            rotateLeft: 70, // F
            rotateRight: 72, // H
            shoot: 82 // R   this is the fire button for the player 4
        }, removePlayer));
        //always take note when changing the controls, the program follows the ascii dec of UPPERCASE letters
    }

    load();

    config.scoreboard = new Scoreboard(config.players);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(config.screen.width, config.screen.height + 100);
    //the 100 was added for the position of scoreboard?

}


function draw() {
    clear();

    config.map.update();
    config.map.draw();

    config.groups.bullets.draw();
    //deleting this will make a bullet invisible

    config.groups.players.overlap(config.groups.bullets, function (player, bullet) {
        var mySound;
        mySound = new Audio("Images/boxHit.wav");
        mySound.play();
        player.spriteEntity.destroy();
        bullet.spriteEntity.destroy();

    });

    for (const player of config.players) {
        player.update(config.players);
        player.draw();
    }

    config.scoreboard.draw();
}

function keyPressed(event) {
    for (const player of config.players) {
        player.keyPressed(event.keyCode);
    }
}

//This function is to stop music
//it doesnt totally work, because when a player gets hit, then the play will go on

function stopMusic() {

    myMusic.pause();
}

function playMusic() {

    myMusic.play();
}
```

Should I add all the js files? It might make the question long, Im new to this stack overflow

About this index.html goes blank
I'm sorry for misunderstanding, the index file doesnt go white and all
What I meant is to be like this

This is the game with 
    `<script src="main.js"></script>`
[image: This is the game with <script src ="main.js">]

This is the game without 
    `<script src="main.js"></script>`
[image: And this is when there is no <script src = "main.js">]

I'm sorry for misunderstanding I have level 0 in communication skills xD

Comment: It's really hard to answer without knowing the contents of your scripts. Please include them as well (or at least, the relevant parts of them), in order to let us know, how your code works! Remember, here, at the other end of this network , we see only what you include the question, and the remaining can only be guessed...

Comment: Sounds like `main.js` is the file that you should have us look at. More specifically, the pats that start the game and the part where you modified the number of players. Creating multiple html files should not be necessary. Also, `[...] removing it will leave the index blank` sounds like the JS runs into an error and stops loading the rest of the file - it might be helpful if you can get us the error message, too.

Comment: I have edited the comment and showed main.js I have no other way how to upload    many js files in one click loolxd

Comment: I edited the *question* and also showed the output when I removed the main.js, Im not sure if the game is still running but I assumed it isn't because there is no main.js right?